# How to get Max Value with in PySpark window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

My data Model is something like Below, trying to get MAX Value within WindowFrame, I am able to model the data but am not sure how to get max Value within Window Frame.

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

I am able to partition and rank, how to get max value(result column) with In Window Frame.

tried like this.

```
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("number").orderBy("version")
wdf=df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(windowSpec))
wdf.show()
```

Comment: can you please add expected output ?

Comment: The data which is in 'result' is expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use `when` function.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
rowId = F.row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy("number").orderBy(col("version").desc())
)
```

```
df
.withColumn("max_value",F.when( rowId == 1,F.lit("Y")).otherwise(F.lit("N")))
.show()
```

```
+---+------+-------+------+---------+
|id |number|version|status|max_value|
+---+------+-------+------+---------+
|102|335762|3      |N     |Y        |
|100|335762|2      |Y     |N        |
|105|47495 |1      |Y     |Y        |
|103|210752|12     |Y     |Y        |
|101|210752|2      |Y     |N        |
|106|210752|1      |Y     |N        |
|104|324916|2      |N     |Y        |
|107|324916|1      |Y     |N        |
+---+------+-------+------+---------+
```

Comment: sorry, I have updated the Expected output, when max(version)== 'Y' In window Frame, all values in that window frame become 'Y', otherwise 'N